# how to access a specific list item without knowing the index in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a long list that's divided among number of subheadings. 
how can i access the last element of the list before certain subheading given that its not the last element of the list. ? can i do that if i have the subheading ID

i.e.

```
<ol>
    <h1 id="heading1"> Heading 1 </h1>
    <li> bla bla bla </li>
    <li> bla bla bla </li>
    <li> I WANT TO ACCESS THIS </li>
    <h1 id="heading2"> Heading 2 </h1>
    <li> bla bla bla </li>
    <li> bla bla bla </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: one more thing .. I DONT KNOW THE INDEX Of the element the list is too long. i want to access it.

Comment: h1 is not valid html inside a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the heading selector and use .prev

```
$('#heading2').prev()
```

Reference from the jQuery api:
http://api.jquery.com/prev/

p.s. H1 inside a list will not validate.

Comment: This will do nothing - there is no previous sibling before #heading1 :)

Comment: Wise guy, aye? :) Changed it to #heading2.